# How to change timestamp in Db2?

Tags: timestamp, db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I have created a table called 'Chicago crime data'
I need to do some queries on it but the table wont load.
The message i get is **(timestamp format does not match data in the column 'UPDATEDON')**

What is populated in the Date column is MM-DD-YYYY, I need to change it to DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS.
I have tried selecting the DD-MM-YYYY under the dropdown of Date Format and then the HH:MM:SS under Timestamp format, but when i complete and begin the load, it says the load succeeded but all 533 rows rejected and when i attempt to view the table (understandably) it says there is no data here yet.

To my understanding you should be able to do a custom change on the time format, but i cant see how?
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

[image: timestamp, time format]
[image: table loaded with errors]

Comment: What is the datatype of column `updatedon`?

Comment: The timestamp format pattern must match _what's in the input file_, not what you want it to be.

Comment: Ah ok thanks guys, your comments has helped. Don’t why it didn’t occur to me before, but I’ll check the above info in the csv file. Let you know the outcome.

Comment: This may help someone else with the same problem. the solution in the end to the above  was a simple one. First drop the table and re-create it, then switch off ' detect data types' button. Click the pencil icon  under the DATE and UPDATEDON column and change to 'VARCHAR' problem solved.

Comment: It is generally a Bad Idea™ to store date-time values in character columns.

Comment: i know but its for an assignment. i didnt create the csv

Answer (score 3):

I too faced the same issue. I fixed it by as below:

1. Paste some random text into TIMESTAMP dropdown field, then you edit option will be enabled for the field
   [As in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aptBT.png)

2. Then enter your desired timestapm(in your case: MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS TT)
3. Ignore the warinigs and proceed further. You will be able to upload without any rejections.

Answer (score 2):

Simply click on the timestamp dropdown and start typing your custom timestamp which in this case is "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS TT"

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem on this IBM course - I found that the way around it was to try to paste something into the Timestamp format box on db2. This worked even though I previously hadn't been able to type in that box, and once I had pasted something I was able to type in that box again.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with pandas:
First I have opened Jupyter-Notebook, and read the csv:

```
    df = pd.read_csv("Chicago_Crime_Data-v2.csv")
```

Then I used this function:

```
    df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)
```

And I save it back to the file:

```
    df.to_csv("Chicago_Crime_Data-v2.csv")
```

Now it would accept it.
(Just see if there is more than one column with this problem)